# Git and an ASP.Net Site?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-2010, c#, asp.net

I would really like to use some actual Revision control (on a WINDOWS TECHNOLOGY?!?!) because I've already done stuff and looked back thinking "this would've been much more successful had I had some revision control."

I personally am falling in love with Git, but I was wondering how well that'd work with C#/asp pages? I have Cygwin so I assume I'd just cd to its directory and run git init, then start using it. But would git screw anything up? I use visual studio 2010 for this project, so I don't know what that'd do.

If you think git would screw with stuff too much do you have another suggestion?

Sorry if you're looking for more info, I'll keep hittin the refresh to update any missing information.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, git will not mess up your files.

A few suggestions for using git on windows if you want somthing more than commandline support.

- [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions)
- [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)
- [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Fantastic thank you very much. I love command line but work requires me on Windows right now so I'd better use some of these extensions.

Comment: Git extensions is pretty awesome.